# Log4Net with AdoAppender but nothing in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, logging, log4net

I try to log error messages using log4net and save them into database using SQL, but nothing happens at all.... Did I miss something? Here is my code

```
            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders(); /*Remove any other appenders*/
            log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger rootLogger = hierarchy.Root;
            rootLogger.Level = hierarchy.LevelMap["ERROR"];


            AdoNetAppender ado = new AdoNetAppender();
            ado.ConnectionType = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
            ado.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSSQLConnectionString_nvn1"];
            ado.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Identity],[Username],[Logger],[Message]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread , @level , @identity , @username ,  @logger, @message)";
            ado.BufferSize = 1;
            ado.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Error;

            AdoNetAppenderParameter logd = new AdoNetAppenderParameter();
            logd.ParameterName = "@log_date";
            logd.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
            logd.Layout = new log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout();
            ado.AddParameter(logd);

                ...........

            ado.ActivateOptions();
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(ado);
```

Thanks.

Summary: Could anyone please check my codes and try to give me some advices about how to save error messages from log4net into a database.

Comment: so what's the question !!

Comment: i want to know if i did something wrong in the code ....:)

Comment: Add this to your app.config: <appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
 </appSettings> You should see some error in VS output window if you debug ...

Answer (score 0):

set buffer size to '1' in config file or in your code as default buffer size is 512:

```
 <bufferSize value="1" />
```

Comment: I would suggest, configure a basic appender first, like logging into a log.txt file. Once that works, you will get to know your configuration needs to be corrected or the way you are using object to log needs to be corrected. Configuration looks to be fine, if you can post where you have used object and that code, it will be helpful to understand. Also what version of DotNet you are using